# How to get required shape files for all zoom levels (z0 to z7) for osm map (vector tiles) Generation from planet.osm.pbf files?

Tags: vector, schema, openstreetmap, vector-tiles

i am working on generating vector tiles for world .well i supposed to use some shape files( like ocean,water,landcover,waterway)  with different files for different zoom levels

**for example :**  ne_110m_glaciated_areas for zoom level 0 and ne_50m_glaciated_areas for zoomlevel 2 ...ect..its from osm schema

i got some general files from some Natural earth data websites..but could not get all of them.So please help me to get all required shape files or do we have to generate them with any tools ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found them from below websites

1.https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/
2.https://github.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/tree/master/10m_cultural

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30367367)